# How to print and format flextables side-by-side in a for loop within RMarkdown

Tags: r, flextable

I have the following Rmd doc where Im generating flextables  within a for loop. This iteration technically prints the tables side by side, but I cannot figure out how to

1. add some space between the two tables.
2. how to keep the size of the rows equal - I don't want the tables to print at the same height if they have a different row count.

   ````
    ---
    title: "Test"
    output: html_document
    ---
    ```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', fig.align='center'}
    library(flextable)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(gridExtra)

    # Loop through data

    overview_table <- function(df) {
      finalTable <- df %>%
      flextable() %>%
      set_header_labels(rowname = "") %>%
      theme_zebra() %>%
      bg(bg="#186183", part="body") %>%
      bg(bg="white", part="header") %>%
      color(part = "body", color = "white") %>%
      height(height = 0.4, part = "header") %>%
      padding(padding.top = 0,
              padding.bottom = 0) %>%
      fontsize(size = 20, part = "body") %>%
      fontsize(size = 18, part = "header") %>%
      align(align = "center", part = "all")
      return(finalTable)
    }

    for (i in 1:3) {

      cat('<center> <h1 style="font-size:80px;">', i, '</h1> <br>')

      a <- overview_table(head(mtcars)[,1:4]) %>%
        gen_grob()
      b <- overview_table(head(mtcars, 10)[,1:4]) %>%
        gen_grob()
      grid.arrange(a,b,ncol = 2)

      #flextable_to_rmd(a)
      cat("</center> <br>")
    }
    ```
   ````